# Orderby Post Views

Tags: order, sort

I want to make a filter list for my posts (in homepage, search page and archive page) Here is an example of what i'm looking for

Sort by:
- Date (/?orderby=date)
- Random (/?orderby=rand)
- Views (here i need an orderby=views or something like that)

I'm counting and viewing post views by using this code:

```
// Count views
function setPostViews($postID) {
  $count_key = 'post_views_count';
  $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
  if($count=='') {
    $count = 0;
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
  } else {
    $count++;
    update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
  }
}

// Show views
function getPostViews($postID) {
  $count_key = 'post_views_count';
  $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
  if($count=='') {
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    return "0 View";
  }
  return $count.' Views';
}

// Show views in WP-Admin
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_column_views');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_column_views', 5, 2);
function posts_column_views($defaults) {
  $defaults['post_views'] = __('Views');
  return $defaults;
}
function posts_custom_column_views($column_name, $id){
  if($column_name === 'post_views') {
    echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort your query by view number, using the meta key :

```
$query = new WP_Query( 
            array( 
                'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'DESC',
            ) 
        );
```

This will query your posts based on the views. You can change `DESC` to `ASC` or `RAND` to achieve what you asked.

To make it work in action, you can use `pre_get_posts()` to filter your query. Use this piece code in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_view_filter' );
function my_view_filter($query){
    if ( 
        !is_admin() && 
        $query->is_main_query() && 
        ( $query->is_home() || $query->is_archive() || $query->is_search() )
    ) {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['orderby'])) {
            $order = $_REQUEST['orderby'];
        }
        if ( $order === 'views') {
            $query->set('meta_key', 'post_views_count');
            $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
            $query->set('order', 'DESC');
        }
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you visit `http://example.com/?orderby=views`, your posts will be filtered by the number of views ( descending, you can change it to anything you want )

Comment: Where I have to put this to make a filter list with 3 options like: option 1 - Date / option 2 - Random / option 3 - Views

Comment: @HankScorpio Hi, You didn't mention where are you going to use this so i posted the general solution for it. Please add more details to your question (including where and how do you want to use this filter, maybe even an example) and possibly add your current code, so i can write an accurate answer.

Comment: Yes, sorry... question edited check it now

Comment: buddy, i received a fatal error when i use your code...
"Fatal error: Call to a member function is_main_query() on null" what it's wrong?

Comment: @HankScorpio Oops sorry, i forgot to add `$query` to the functions arguments. It should be `my_view_filter($query)` instead of `my_view_filter()`.

Comment: Thanks buddy, it's working now... you save my life i love you :)

Comment: @HankScorpio You're welcome mate! Glad it helped you.

Comment: you're a php developer? i need a fix for this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269119/custom-taxonomy-list-with-pagination-and-sortby-letter and then my theme is ready to go. Can i send you a private message here in stack? i cant find the option (i want to hire you, if you want, to solve my problem)

Comment: @HankScorpio I will take a look into your question for sure, but stack exchange does not have a messaging system for the very exact reason of personal benefits. It does however have chatrooms, which you can join after reaching 20 reputation point ( i think it's 20 ).