# Custom taxonomy list and sortby letter pagination problem

Tags: pagination, terms, sort

I'm getting a taxonomy list page with pagination using this code :

```
<?php
$sortby = $_GET['sortby'];
if(isset($_GET['showall'])):
$args = array('hide_empty' => 0);
else:
$page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$per_page = 1; //number of actores to show per page
$offset = ($page-1) * $per_page;
$args = array('number' => $per_page, 'offset' => $offset, 'hide_empty' => 0);
                        endif;
$taxonomy = 'actores';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args);
?>
<?php foreach ($tax_terms as $cat) : ?>
<?php $flag = 0; if($sortby == substr($cat->name, 0, 1) || $sortby == '') {$flag = 1;} if($flag == '1') { ?>
<div class="td-block-span-actores">
<div class="td_module_3 td_module_wrap td-animation-stack">
<div class="td-module-image">
<div class="td-module-thumb-actores">
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'actores'); ?>">
<?php $actores_image = z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); if(!empty($actores_image)) : ?>
<img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" alt title="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>" />
<?php else : ?>
<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/no-thumb/td_386x520.png" alt title="<?php echo $cat->name; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="entry-title td-module-title">
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat->slug, 'actores'); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a>
</div>
<span class="count">
<?php echo $cat->count; ?> <?php if($cat->count > 1) {
_e('Videos');
} else {
_e('Video');
} ?>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['showall'])):
$total_terms = wp_count_terms('actores');
$pages = ceil($total_terms / $per_page);
if($pages > 1):
echo '<div class="page-nav td-pb-padding-side">';
echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => preg_replace('/\?.*/', '/', get_pagenum_link(1)) . '%_%',
'format' => 'page/%#%/',
'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
'total' => ceil($total_terms / $per_page),
'current' => $page,
));
echo '<div class="page-nav td-pb-padding-side"><a href="'.get_permalink().'?showall=true">Show all</a></div>';
echo "<span class=\"pages\">Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
echo '</div>';
endif;
else:
echo '<div class="page-nav td-pb-padding-side"><a href="'.get_permalink().'">Show numeric pagination</a></div>';
endif;
?>
```

And this code for sortby letter function:

```
<?php
// a to z pagination
if(!function_exists('a_to_z_pagination')) {
function a_to_z_pagination() {
$order = isset($_REQUEST['sortby']) ? trim($_REQUEST['sortby']) : null;
$sort_array = array(
'A' =>  __('A'),
'B' =>  __('B'),
'C' =>  __('C'),
'D' =>  __('D'),
'E' =>  __('E'),
'F' =>  __('F'),
'G' =>  __('G'),
'H' =>  __('H'),
'I' =>  __('I'),
'J' =>  __('J'),
'K' =>  __('K'),
'L' =>  __('L'),
'M' =>  __('M'),
'N' =>  __('N'),
'O' =>  __('O'),
'P' =>  __('P'),
'Q' =>  __('Q'),
'R' =>  __('R'),
'S' =>  __('S'),
'T' =>  __('T'),
'U' =>  __('U'),
'V' =>  __('V'),
'W' =>  __('W'),
'X' =>  __('X'),
'Y' =>  __('Y'),
'Z' =>  __('Z'),
);
foreach ($sort_array as $key => $value) {
$active = ($order == $key) ? 'page-numbers current' : null;
$block .= '<a class="'.$active.'" href="'.get_permalink().'?sortby='.$key.'">'.$value.'</a>';
}
print $block;
}
add_action('a_to_z_pagination', 'a_to_z_pagination');
}
```

My problem is that i'm getting empty pages when i use the sortby letter...

Example:

I have 4 custom tax "actores"

1 tax per page

4 pages

tax slug: Ana, Brian, Carlos, Diana,

when i sortby letter "B" i get

page 1 - empty (actores/page/1/?sortby=B)

page 2 - Brian (actores/page/2/?sortby=B)

page 3 - empty (actores/page/3/?sortby=B)

page 4 - empty (actores/page/4/?sortby=B)

Comment: downvoted as question should be complete with all the data in them, including the relevant code.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Dear mark, IMHO it would be nicer to just edit the question, adding the missing data from the link and noting the OP about what he should do himself.

Comment: @MarkKaplun sorry mark, code edited by jack :)

Comment: @JackJohansson, and then people will think I am a nice person.... can't let that happen. Anyway the chunks of code without no explanation what are they doing, are not a huge improvement (usually people that use pastebin just dump their whole code there, hiding the trees in the forest ;) )

Comment: @MarkKaplun I never thought of that, kappa ;) Let me tell your about my very first question, commented by you ( in the Loop chat room).

Comment: @JackJohansson I have a reputation I am trying to keep here. Trying to serve as the "do not do what he does" example :)

Comment: @MarkKaplun if you cant help me, stop commenting, dont be mad, it was my fault... Sorry buddy, i'm new here :D

Comment: @HankScorpio, sorry about that. The problem seems to be that you expect `get_terms` to have a pagination capabilities, while IMO it doesn't. In addition it is generally not a good idea to reuse wordpress parameters like `paged` for something that do not work with the wordpress core loops

Comment: @MarkKaplun No problem, i noticed that the sortby letter function is doing the same that "showall" (my previous sort function to "show all my taxonomies in 1 page).  What do you recommend me to do to show a list of actors with pagination? (and sortby letter) the code that i'm using is from my old theme, i just copy pasted into a new one :d

Comment: simple but not so simple solution, this sounds like you should have a CPT of actors, this will also make it so much easier to maintain their bio and use simple theme templates for them. With the CPT you can use a taxonomy for the letters to construct the relevant archive pages. The simple but ugly solution is to sort the get_terms results and show them based on the "page" that you pass as a parameters in the URL (add a rewrite rule for nice URL). than you will have to implement the paging navigation as well.

Comment: I have a suspicion that at this point the second option will be faster for you but ugly

Comment: @MarkKaplun custom post type? i can use actors (custom post type) into a normal post? like a custom taxonomy?

Comment: nothing is easy, so no ;) if you do not have a very huge DB, you can make your own meta box and associate them with actors, or associate them with the actor taxonomy terms (add a meta to each term with the post id of the relevant page). It is a betterr DB structure, but saying all this things out loud make me realise it is not very trivial, OTOH if you want to be able to search in actors bio, or group actors by another taxonomy, I am not sure there is a better way. So I guess the decision should be based upon how complex is your actor data going to be

Comment: it's a good idea, now i'm using a custom taxonomy and term_description to display actor bio, this is not a big deal for me, i really dont need those things so far (like hair color, age, etc) but if custom post type is easy to put in a list with pagination maybe i can try to learn how to... so thank you buddy

Comment: @MarkKaplun "CPT-onomies: Using Custom Post Types as Taxonomies" if you want, search this plugin and tell me if you're talking about something like this. Thanks

Comment: yes, sounds exactly what I meant

Comment: @MarkKaplun i found a problem with this plugin, i need to create an "actor" (custom post type) before i can use it into a normal post... And i cant f ind any info on how to use cpt as a taxonomy for normal posts without plugin, any suggestion?

Comment: just create the cpt and the taxonomy. the biggest challenge is to keep them in sync, so for example when you create an actor post, you hook on the save_post" hook and create a "actor" taxonomy term, and set a "post_id" meta to point to the actors post.

Comment: .... but maybe with that plugin you can associate the taxonomy with normal posts as well. There has to be an API for that but right now I don't remember it :( .... register_taxonomy_for_object_type is probably the winner

Comment: @MarkKaplun i'm having some problems with cpt template, so i decided to try back my taxonomy page... i was thinking about a custom search form into actors page, that only search for actors or first letter, this is possible? because i cant solve the sortby pagination so maybe a searchform can be good for now, thanks

Comment: @JackJohansson i'm having some problems with cpt template, so i decided to try back my taxonomy page... i was thinking about a custom search form into actors page, that only search for actors or first letter, this is possible? because i cant solve the sortby pagination so maybe a searchform can be good for now, thanks

Comment: @HankScorpio Yes i did something similar for my blog too. You can ask a new question about this and add any sort of code you are using now, so i can post an answer for you.

Comment: @JackJohansson question edited to avoid spam because i'm using the same code...